# Elección de un elemento mediante un número aleatorio, suma acumulativa

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente estructura:

```
probabilidad = runif(5)
probabilidad= probabilidad/sum(probabilidad)
names(probabilidad) = LETTERS[1:5]
probabilidad
         A          B          C          D          E 
0.30918062 0.17969799 0.15695684 0.09655216 0.25761238 
sum(probabilidad)
[1] 1
```

Cómo podéis ver, la suma de sus valores es 1, ya que son probabilidades. Genero un número aleatorio entre 0-1:

```
runif(1)
```

Éste número me servirá cómo selector para mi estructura, es decir, si el número aleatorio fuese **0.34** elegiríamos el elemento **B** ya que el número se encuentra en el segmento entre la suma A y B, son sumas acumulativas,

```
0.30918062 + 0.17969799 = 0.48
```

No sé cómo puede elegir el elemento por medio de la probabilidad proporcionada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma que se me ocurre, es calculando en primer lugar la suma acumulativa mediante [`cumsum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html), luego buscamos la menor suma mayor al elemento buscado y mediante [`match()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) ubicamos el índice sobre el vector original. Algo así:

```
valor = 0.41
s <- cumsum(probabilidad)
probabilidad[match(min(s[s>=valor])[1],s)]

valor
probabilidad
s
```

La salida:

```
> valor
[1] 0.41
> probabilidad
         A          B          C          D          E 
0.18413659 0.23991206 0.26581474 0.07141827 0.23871835 
> s
        A         B         C         D         E 
0.1841366 0.4240486 0.6898634 0.7612817 1.0000000 
> probabilidad[match(min(s[s>=valor]),s)[1]]
        B 
0.2399121
```

Verificamos que efectivamente el valor `0.41` se encuentra entre los intervalos `A`y `B` (de la suma acumulativa) , por lo que nos quedamos con el límite superior según tu definición, es decir el valor de `B`.

Nota: Hacemos `match(...)[1]` para los eventuales casos que tuviéramos dos valores iguales, nos quedamos con el primero.

La otra forma, incluso más simple que podría usarse es mediante la función [`findInterval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html):

```
probabilidad[findInterval(valor, cumsum(probabilidad)) + 1]
```

Nota: como por defecto nos devuelve el límite inferior, debemos sumar 1 al índice